Corner Radius of image from UIKit
I am trying to make the image captured by this camera view have a corner radius of 24 but it does not seem to be working. I've provided the code below.
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation

struct CameraView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController
    
    let cameraService: CameraService
    let didFinishProcessingPhoto: (Result<AVCapturePhoto, Error>) -> ()
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        
        cameraService.start(delegate: context.coordinator) { error in
            if let error = error {
                didFinishProcessingPhoto(.failure(error))
                return
            }
        }
        
        let viewController = UIViewController()
        viewController.view.backgroundColor = .black
        viewController.view.layer.addSublayer(cameraService.previewLayer)
        cameraService.previewLayer.frame = viewController.view.bounds
        cameraService.previewLayer.cornerRadius = 24
        return viewController
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self, didFinishProcessingPhoto: didFinishProcessingPhoto)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) { }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
        let parent: CameraView
        private var didFinishProcessingPhoto: (Result<AVCapturePhoto, Error>) -> ()
        
        init(_ parent: CameraView, didFinishProcessingPhoto: @escaping (Result<AVCapturePhoto, Error>) -> ()) {
            self.parent = parent
            self.didFinishProcessingPhoto = didFinishProcessingPhoto
        }
        
        func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: (any Error)?) {
            if let error = error {
                didFinishProcessingPhoto(.failure(error))
                return
            }
            didFinishProcessingPhoto(.success(photo))
        }
    }
}

If it is of any relevance, I have also attached the context of the CameraView from the parent view.
if let capturedImage = capturedImage {
    Image(uiImage: capturedImage)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: size.width * 0.2)
} else {
    CameraView(cameraService: cameraService) { result in
        switch result {
            
        case .success(let photo):
            if let data = photo.fileDataRepresentation() {
                capturedImage = UIImage(data: data)
            } else {
                print("Error: no image data found")
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    .onTapGesture(count: 2) {
        toggleCameraFunctionAndAnimation()
    }
    .gesture(
        MagnificationGesture()
            .onChanged { value in
                scaleFactor = value.magnitude
                cameraService.zoom(scaleFactor)
            }
    )
    .onDisappear {
        cameraService.stopRunningImageCamera()
    }
}

Where capturedImage is an optional UIImage. As shown, I have tried changing the corner radius of the captured image inside the UIViewController and inside the parent view as an Image(uiImage: ...) and both approaches don't seem to be working. Any clarity someone can give me on this I'd really appreciate.

you forgot to implement update, e.g.
func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
    context.coordinator.didFinishProcessingPhoto = didFinishProcessingPhoto
}

Also, makeCoordinator should just be:
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
    Coordinator()
}

self in this case is a value so you can't pass it like an object reference because it will go out of date the next time this struct is init.
